# how to repeat tpl blocks inside tpl

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a boxcomponent that I'm creating with a tpl. So in initTemplate I set the template I want by doing

```
this.tpl = new Ext.Xtemplate( my_template ).
```

So in my_template, which is a bit long actually, I have a block which I wish to repeat more than once inside my_template. 
What's the best way to achieve that? I wish I didn't have to copy the block over and over, specially if that block is long.

for example, let's say that my_template =

```
'<tpl for="value1">',
   '<div class="c1">{a}</div>',
   '<div class="c2">{b}</div>', 
'</tpl>'

'<tpl for="value2">',
    '<div class="c1">{a}</div>',
    '<div class="c2">{b}</div>', 
'</tpl>'
```

my data looks like:

```
data = {
 value1: {
   a: 'blah',
   b: 'bleh'
 }
 value2: {
   a: 'bloh',
   b: 'bluh'
 }
}
```

So, in my example, I'd like to know if there's a way to sort of call a function that will repeat

```
'<div class="c1">{a}</div>',
'<div class="c2">{b}</div>',
```

So I'd have

```
'<tpl for="value1">',
    myFunction();
'</tpl>'

'<tpl for="value2">',
    myFunction();
'</tpl>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is entirely different question, after you have edited it. Nevermind, the answer is yes, you can use member functions to generate the content. This is example from XTemplate docs. As you can see, anything returned from `isBaby` and `isGirl` methods below is rendered in the resulting html. You only need to set `myFunction` and then call it within the template: `this.myFunction()`

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<p>Name: {name}</p>',
    '<p>Kids: ',
    '<tpl for="kids">',
        '<tpl if="this.isGirl(name)">',
            '<p>Girl: {name} - {age}</p>',
        '<tpl else>',
            '<p>Boy: {name} - {age}</p>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<tpl if="this.isBaby(age)">',
            '<p>{name} is a baby!</p>',
        '</tpl>',
    '</tpl></p>',
    {
        // XTemplate configuration:
        disableFormats: true,
        // member functions:
        isGirl: function(name){
           return name == 'Aubrey' || name == 'Nikol';
        },
        isBaby: function(age){
           return age < 1;
        }
    }
);
tpl.overwrite(panel.body, data);
```

And data:

```
var data = {
    name: 'Don Griffin',
    title: 'Senior Technomage',
    company: 'Sencha Inc.',
    drinks: ['Coffee', 'Water', 'More Coffee'],
    kids: [
        { name: 'Aubrey',  age: 17 },
        { name: 'Joshua',  age: 13 },
        { name: 'Cale',    age: 10 },
        { name: 'Nikol',   age: 5 },
        { name: 'Solomon', age: 0 }
    ]
};
```

Comment: actually, i didn't mean to manipulate the variables. They will probably stay the same.. What I meant was to actually repeat a piece of template, such as '<div class="c1">{a}</div>','<div class="c2">{b}</div>', and I'm not sure if I can use those functions withing a template to accomplish that

Comment: oh, I think I can use template functions and do '{[this.templateFunction()]}'! :) I just don't know yet how to pass a class variable inside that function without passing all i need in the argument, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if data you feed into the template also repeats - if it is an array. As you have `<tpl for=".">`, you can have `<tpl for="innerArray">` so if your data looks similar to the following:

```
[
    {item:'value', innerArray:[{
        innerItem:'value1'
    },{
        innerItem:'value2'
    }]}
]
```

it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately I'm not sure how this will help me.. You're probably saying the right thing, but I'm not getting it. I've edited my question so I make myself more clear, since I realize I did not specify how my data would look like (like you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

```
new Ext.XTemplate([
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div>',
                '<tpl for="list">',
                    '{[ this.getTemplateIfDataPresent(values, "key_a") ]}',
                    '{[ this.getTemplateIfDataPresent(values, "key_b") ]}',
                '</tpl> ',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
        ].join(""), {
    compiled: true,
    templateStr: '<p> {0}: <b>{1}</b> </p>',
    getTemplate: function(values, key) {
        if (!values || !values[key]) {
            return '-';
        }

        var result = String.format(this.templateStr, key, values.list[key]);
        return result;
    }
});
```